# React Link to current URL does not reload page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an image logo on my ReactJS website which has a link to load the current page URL. I can see that the URL is correct (when I hover on the image, the correct URL is displayed at the bottom left corner of the browser), but when I click on the image the page does not reload (it does essentially nothing, not even a re-render).

```
<Link to={`${window.location.pathname}`}>
     <img className="img-fluid" src={Logo} alt="Alt_Text" />
</Link>
```

Is there any way to reload the page without using an onClick handler in the Link?

Comment: React router won't do anything if a link is pointing to the current URL, if you need to reload, use JavaScript to do so

Comment: @ale917k I don't want to force my page to reload. I mean, a link should point to a resource. Doesn't matter if it's back to the already loaded resource. Also, in future, I might use only part of the already loaded link, so a reload wouldn't solve my use case then.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. You want to reload the page and don't want to reload the page, which is it? If you are already on the page the link points to, this is a non-op. If the link points elsewhere, a navigation action occurs. The `Link` component and `react-router-dom` only manipulates the URL in the address bar, it doesn't reload anything. Can you update your question to clarify your use case and issue in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try these:

user Link:

```
 <Link to={`${window.location.pathname}`} onClick={()=>{window.location.reload()}}> <img className="img-fluid" src={Logo} alt="Alt_Text /></Link>
```

Or use a tag:

```
 <a href={`${window.location.pathname}`}><img className="img-fluid" src={Logo} alt="Alt_Text /></a>
```

Comment: The <a> tag worked! I didn't want to force my page to reload so I guess this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to force the window to reload, you can try to use **window.location.reload()** in any event you wanna trigger.

React-Router-Dom will only redirect your url history only if it detects any change, and it will not reload page at all because React is typically used to build Single-Page-Application (SPA). Therefore, what you are asking is contradicting to the principle of React and React-Router-Dom.

Comment: Yeah, I don't want to force my page to reload. I mean, when I think of a link, I imagine a path pointing to some place. Doesn't matter if it's back to the same page or not. And whenever a new page loads, there should be a visual indication of it. But thanks for the explanation about React-Router-Dom. I now understand why I cannot use just a Link.

Comment: using window.localtion.reload might lost data want send throught link